# how to simulate Windows 8.1's "Change PC Settings" UI in xaml

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

What controls were used to make it? It functions like a tab control in windows form applications. but there is no tab control in windows 8.1 xaml.